# Find GPA using function

Tags: python

This is supposed to be the code for the calculation of the semester GPA on the basis of the grade acquired and the credits of the classes.

There must be use of the `coursePoints(credit, grade)` function to calculate the GPA.

But here in my code, the `credit` value is not changing and an error occurs.

```
classnum=int(input("Enter the num of classes: "))

totalcredit=0
totalgpa=0

def main():
    for i in range(1,classnum+1):
        print("class", i)
        credit=int(input("Enter the credit: "))
        grade=str(input("Enter the grade: "))
        totalgpa+=coursePoints(credit,grade)
        totalcredit+=credit

    totalcourse=classnum 
    semestergpa=totalgpa/totalcredit
    print("Semester summary")
    print("courses taken: ", classnum)
    print("credits taken: ", totalcredit)
    print("GPA points: ", totalgpa)
    print("Semester GPA: ", semestergpa)

def coursePoints(Credit,Grade):
    if Grade == 'A+' or Grade == 'a+':
        return 4*Credit
    elif Grade == 'A' or Grade == 'a':
        return 4*Credit
    elif Grade == 'A-' or Grade == 'a-':
        return 3.67*Credit
    elif Grade == 'B+' or Grade == 'b+':
        return 3.33*Credit
    elif Grade == 'B' or Grade =='b':
        return 3*Credit
    elif Grade == 'B-' or Grade == 'b-':
        return 2.67*Credit
    elif Grade == 'C+' or Grade == 'c+':
        return 2.33*Credit
    elif Grade == 'C' or Grade == 'c':
        return 2*Credit               
    elif Grade == 'C-' or Grade == 'c-':                        
        return 1.67*Credit                
    elif Grade =='D+' or Grade == 'd+':                      
        return 1.33*Credit                
    elif Grade == 'D' or Grade == 'd':                        
        return 1*Credit                      
    elif Grade == 'D-' or Grade == 'd-':                                
        return 0.33*Credit                     
    else:
        return 0

main()
```

Comment: Should C+, B- and D- be lowercase in the second equality?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Could you help for the correction regarding the function?

Comment: Please use the edit link above the comments here to clarify what error occurs

Comment: How is your code even running? Having an assignment in the return area, as you are doing, should be a syntactic error. I'm referring to this: `return gpa = 4*Credit` and the other return statements

Comment: Well I see you edited the post to remove that, so never mind I guess.

Comment: The changes have been made as you all have suggested. Thank to you all for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are returning a variable assignment.

```
return gpa = 4*Credit
```

You don't need the equal sign, just do

```
return 4*Credit
```

Fix all of your return statements like that.

Also, edits have been made to your question for indentation, so that might have also been a problem, but it looks like those were fixed, and to get your correct logic, please fix the capitalization of your grades, as I mentioned in the comments.